# Crear una función que verifique que una variable de tipo TextField sea double

Tags: java, javafx

Necesito ayuda ideando una función que devuelva un *boolean* si lo que esta en un *TextField* de *javafx* es un dato *double* o no
algo parecido a esto:

```
public boolean isSampleValid(TextField numfield){
     if(numfield.getText() iinstanceof Double){ return true;}
     else{return false}
}
```

Tengo claro que esa comparación no se puede hacer por que se estaría comparando un *String* con un *double*.

¿Hay algún método para verificar esto?

Comment: Prueba con [`Double.parseDouble(numfield.getText());`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-). Si la cadena no se reconoce como un número arrojará una excepción, donde al cacharla podrás regresar false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar el método `Double.valueOf(String s)`. Necesitarías usar un `try/catch` ya que dicho método lanzará una excepción cuando el valor no sea un *double*.

El método puede quedar así:

```
public boolean isDouble(String string)
{
    try {
        Double.valueOf(string);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Te dejo un pequeño replt.it para que veas como funciona:
https://replit.com/@JacoboTapia/StringToDouble#Main.java

Comment: Me funciono! estaba pesando que debia usar try/catch pero no sabia como implementarlo.Muchas gracias!!